# How do you open up a context menu in a soft keyboard by pressin onto a soft key?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

For example when i select on the "Done" soft key in the virtual keyboard, it should trigger the context menu to show options such as 
"option 1", 
"option 2", 
"option 3" 
with a title of "Options.

Below is a simplified version of my xml file.

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:verticalGap="0px"
android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
>

<Row>
    <Key android:codes="1" android:keyLabel="Encrypt" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="2" android:keyLabel="Translate"/>
    <Key android:codes="3" android:keyLabel="Done" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the context menu see the below code:

**In Activity onCreate method:**

```
  key.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

       @Override  
       public void onClick(View v) {  
        //Creating the instance of PopupMenu  
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button1);  
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());  

        //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener  
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
         public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
          return true;  
         }  
        });  

        popup.show();//showing popup menu
       }  
      });//closing the setOnClickListener method
```

**File: poupup_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  

<item  
    android:id="@+id/one"  
    android:title="One"/>  

<item  
    android:id="@+id/two"  
    android:title="Two"/>  

<item  
    android:id="@+id/three"  
    android:title="Three"/>  

</menu>
```

Comment: However, the class i am working on has already extends with InputMethodService already. Because I am working on the sample code provided by Eclipse ADT Budle. How do i extends Activity as well?

Comment: Can you show the code? We cant extend 2 classes at a time.

Comment: Im sorry the code is too long. If we cant extend 2 classes at the same time then what can i do to solve the problem of the need to extend 2 classes?

Answer (score 0):

Your soft keyboards keypresses are handled in a service that extends InputMethodService and implements onKeyboardActionListener.

In the service, where you are handling Key-presses on the softkeyboard, add the Popup menu code you would otherwise use with an onscreen button in an app.
Like so:

```
public class MyKeyboardService extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener
{
    private KeyboardView viewOfKeyboard;
    private Keyboard theKeyboardLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView()
    {
        viewOfKeyboard = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard1, null);
        theKeyboardLayout = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboardlayout);
        viewOfKeyboard.setKeyboard(theKeyboardLayout);
        viewOfKeyboard.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return viewOfKeyboard;
    }


    .................//InputMethodService methods goes here

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes)
    {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();

        switch(primaryCode){ 
        case -222: //-222 is just a random ID number I assigned my key on the softkeyboard.
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MyKeyboardService.this, viewOfKeyboard);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, popup.getMenu());
            //menu_main being the xml file for the popup menu
            popup.show();
            break;
    }
}
```

From there, just add code to handle button click in your popup menu as you would normally.

The menu_main XML file for reference:

```
< menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
      < item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>
      < item android:id="@+id/button1"
              android:title="button1"/>
< /menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I don't think he'll be able to update or get any text from current input connection from popup menu inside Marshmallow. Something wrong and I opened a bug report about that. Have you tested it in Marshmallow?